# interleaving 2 lists of unequal lengths

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

I want to be able to interleave two lists that could potentially be unequal in length. What I have is:

```
  def interleave(xs,ys):
    a=xs
    b=ys
    c=a+b
    c[::2]=a
    c[1::2]=b
    return c
```

This works great with lists that either equal in length or just +/-1. But if let's say xs=[1,2,3] and ys= ["hi,"bye","no","yes","why"] this message appears:

```
c[::2]=a
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 3 to extended slice of size 4
```

How do I fix this with using indexing? or do I have to use for loops? 
EDIT: what I want is to have the extra values just appear at the end.

Comment: What do you want to happen? What should the output be?

Comment: @DavidRobinson what I want to do is have the extra values appear at the end.

Comment: So `[1, "hi, 2, "bye", 3, "no","yes","why"]`?

Comment: @DavidRobinson yes exactly

Comment: Is this a quiz question?

Comment: @wwii no its for practice

Comment: There are two separate duplicate links because of ambiguity in the specification.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) here:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> xs = [1,2,3]
>>> ys = ["hi","bye","no","yes","why"]
>>> s = object()
>>> [y for x in izip_longest(xs, ys, fillvalue=s) for y in x if y is not s]
[1, 'hi', 2, 'bye', 3, 'no', 'yes', 'why']
```

---

Using `roundrobin` recipe from [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes), no sentinel value required here:

```
from itertools import *
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> list(roundrobin(xs, ys))
[1, 'hi', 2, 'bye', 3, 'no', 'yes', 'why']
>>> list(roundrobin(ys, xs))
['hi', 1, 'bye', 2, 'no', 3, 'yes', 'why']
```

Comment: I have a zip function I made that zips xs and ys. can I use that instead?

Comment: @user2829177 `izip_longest` is slightly different than `zip`, `zip` truncates the output to the shortest list.

Comment: is there a much simpler approach?

Comment: @user2829177 You might find the roundrobin recipe from itertools a bit helpful. I've posted that in my answer.

Comment: @user2829177 Check out DSM's first solution, IMO that's the simplest approach.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `heapq.merge`:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3]
ys = ['hi', 'bye', 'no', 'yes', 'why']

import heapq
interleaved = [v for i, v in heapq.merge(*[enumerate(el) for el in (xs, ys)])]
# [1, 'hi', 2, 'bye', 3, 'no', 'yes', 'why']
```

This avoids the need for a sentinel value and flattening.

Use the [roundrobin recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) instead to achieve this more effectively without having items be comparable.

Comment: It has been drilled into me not to modify the contents of a sequence that is being iterated over with a for loop.  Is this a case of, don't do it *unless you know what you are doing*?  I'm trying to work out why it is OK in this generator, any hints?

Comment: @wwii It's not a good idea. (Blame it on an 11pm while tired post). It will work for 2 sequences. However, for consecutively equal length length ones preceding a shorter one - the order of the next items goes "wonky" - using the `roundroubin` recipe is the correct way to do this... I have removed the code and updated answer to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here's my entry:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> xs = [1,2,3]
>>> ys = ["hi","bye","no","yes","why"]
>>> xi, yi = iter(xs), iter(ys)
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(xi, yi))) + list(xi) + list(yi)
[1, 'hi', 2, 'bye', 3, 'no', 'yes', 'why']
```

Alternatively,

```
>>> [i for row in zip(xi, yi) for i in row] + list(xi) + list(yi)
```

would have worked too (that's just the listcomp idiom for flattening, as used by @hcwhsa).  My first thought was

```
>>> list(zip(*sorted(list(enumerate(xs)) + list(enumerate(ys)))))[1]
(1, 'hi', 2, 'bye', 3, 'no', 'yes', 'why')
```

but that's just a much less efficient version of @Jon Clements (I used an inefficient sort, he used an efficient heap queue.)

[I've been experimenting trying to get something using `cycle` working, but it doesn't seem to be as easy as I'd hoped: and it turns out that I was simply working toward reimplementing the roundrobin recipe that @hcwsha posted, so there's no point in finishing that. :^) ]

Comment: We're actually chatting a bit about this in the Python room - On Python 3.x, our approaches will break because of the need to do comparisons.... :)

Comment: @Jon Clements: Hey, my official entry will work, there are no comparisons there. :^)

Comment: Yeah... I had noticed I'd also re-written a non-itertools version of roundrobin :)

Answer (score 0):

Kept it simple:

```
def interleave(xs,ys):
    stop = min(len(xs), len(ys))
    suffix = max(xs, ys, key = len)[stop:]
    out = list()
    for pair in zip(xs, ys):
        out.extend(pair)
    out.extend(suffix)
    return out
```

Caveats:
Python 2.7
Assumes lists are passed as the arguments.

Comment: I think your `out += xs[index] + ys[index]` line would need to be `out += [xs[index], ys[index]]`, or use 1-element slices or something to make sure you're concatenating lists.  And there's no `xrange` in Python 3.  But those are easily fixed.

Comment: @DSM, I tried it on a single test case and it works, ```interleave(list('ab'), list('cdefghijklmnop'))```.  Should I state that my answers are Python 2?  Is there an assumption, here, that answers are 3 unless stated otherwise?

Comment: Your test case is a little special because they're one-character strings.  Try `[1,2,3]` and `['hi', 'bye', 'no', 'yes', 'why']`, or even `['ab','cd'],['ef','gh']`.  As for the Python 3 thing, I'm sorry -- I was sure that the question had the python 3 tag, and it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge.  Fixed.  While fixing it, reminded me of something I'd already seen.

Comment: what if I'm not allowed to use any functions other than : len, range, list, str, print, and .append? I have a function for finding the minimum so I've ajusted that. But I don't understand how I can go about replacing the .extend @wwii

Comment: zip() creates a list of tuples.  Instead of extending ```out``` with the tuple, you can unpack the tuple, ```for first, second in zip(xs, ys):```, and append first and second to out.  To append suffix you would need to iterate over suffix and append each element to out.  You might want to add those (and any other) specs to your question.