# interlacing strings in python

Tags: python, string, zip

I had a question for a test where I had to interlace letters from two strings into one, I did it using the following code:

'abcd' and 'efghi' -> 'aebfcgdhi'

```
s1,s2='abcd' ,'efghi'
t=[a+b for a,b in zip(s1, s2) ]
ls1 = len(s1)
ls2 = len(s2)
if ls1 > ls2:
    t.extend(s1[ls2:])
elif ls1 < ls2:
    t.extend(s2[ls1:])
print ''.join(t)
```

I first tried using the following which seems to work only when strings are the same length or s2 is the longer string.

```
 print  ''.join([a+b for a,b in zip(s1, s2)]) + max(s1,s2)[min(len(s1),len(s2)):]
```

Where did I go wrong in my logic?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @thefourtheye edited question to include expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [interleaving 2 lists of unequal lengths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883826/interleaving-2-lists-of-unequal-lengths)

Comment: @hcwhsa I dont want to use itertools, my question is how to modify my own code to get required output or if it is possible at all so I can understand exactly how it works.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Have you checked DSM's [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19884254/846892) on that thread?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Please check Edit 2 in my solution. That will make your sure that your program will work properly.

Comment: @hcwhsa I checked out all the answers, his solution works but I don't understand how it works as to me it is not very transparent , I don't need the answer to solve a question as I already have a working solution, I am trying to understand where my first solution went wrong.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You mean, you didnt understand my answer?

Comment: @thefourtheye, no I was talking about the answer that hcwhsa directed me to on another similar thread.

Comment: I gave two duplicate links because of an ambiguity in the specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code work, you just need to use the `key` param in the `max` function

```
print  ''.join([a+b for a,b in zip(s1, s2)]) + max(s1,s2, key=len)[min(len(s1),len(s2)):]
```

Alternatively, you can use [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to iterate till the biggest of the two iterables is exhausted. So, this solution works irrespective of the lengths of strings.

```
import itertools
s1,s2='abcd' ,'efghi'
print "".join(y for x in itertools.izip_longest(s1, s2) for y in x if y)
```

**Output**

```
aebfcgdhi
```

**Edit:**

Without using `itertools`

```
s1,s2='abcd' ,'efghi'
minLen = min(len(s1), len(s2))
print "".join(y for x in zip(s1, s2) for y in x) + s1[minLen:] + s2[minLen:]
```

Comment: how to do it without using itertools?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Please check now

Comment: I have not seen the use of key before when using max. That was so simple, thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Without using `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
>>> s1, s2 = 'abcd', 'efghi'
>>> l = min(len(s1), len(s2))
>>> ''.join(a+b for a, b in zip(s1, s2)) + s1[l:] + s2[l:]
'aebfcgdhi'
```

Comment: i know this is a very old thread, but since your solution worked perfectly, could you explain how to un-interlace it?

Comment: @shamilpython, Please post a separate question (not comment) with example.