# Round Robin method of mixing of two lists in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

If input is

```
round_robin(range(5), "hello")
```

I need output as

```
[0, 'h', 1, 'e', 2, 'l', 3, 'l', 4, 'o']
```

I tried

```
def round_robin(*seqs):
list1=[]
length=len(seqs)
list1= cycle(iter(items).__name__ for items in seqs)
while length:
    try:
        for x in list1:
            yield x
    except StopIteration:
        length -= 1

pass
```

but it gives error as

```
AttributeError: 'listiterator' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

How to modify the code to get the desired output?

Comment: `[ i for t in  zip(range(5), "hello") for i in t]`

Comment: `roundrobin` recipe is already present in itertools's docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes

Comment: Related: [Interleaving 2 lists of unequal lengths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883826/interleaving-2-lists-of-unequal-lengths)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could find a series of iteration recipes here: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes

```
from itertools import islice, cycle


def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))


print list(roundrobin(range(5), "hello"))
```

**EDIT**: Python 3

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))

print(list(roundrobin(range(5), "hello")))
```

Comment: it is not working for round_robin([1, 2], "a", (5, 6, 7), [4])

Comment: @riteshbhat I obtain: [1, 'a', 5, 4, 2, 6, 7]. Which version of python are you running?

Comment: python 2.7.6 This is my o/p    [1, 'a', 5, 4, 2, 6, <itertools.cycle object at 0x025AD8C8>]

Comment: Im using python 2.7.5 but your o/p it's very strange. Are you sure you copied this code?

Comment: Oh yeah ur code works perfect i has done small mistake. Thanks :)

Comment: This recipe may not work for Python >=3; see the [updated itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function and then flatten the result with list comprehension, like this

```
def round_robin(first, second):
    return[item for items in zip(first, second) for item in items]
print round_robin(range(5), "hello")
```

**Output**

```
[0, 'h', 1, 'e', 2, 'l', 3, 'l', 4, 'o']
```

`zip` function groups the values from both the iterables, like this

```
print zip(range(5), "hello") # [(0, 'h'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'l'), (3, 'l'), (4, 'o')]
```

We take each and every tuple and flatten it out with list comprehension.

But as @Ashwini Chaudhary suggested, use [roundrobin receipe from the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
from itertools import cycle
from itertools import islice
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))

print list(roundrobin(range(5), "hello"))
```

Comment: What if sequences are of unequal length?

Comment: @thefourtheye I am making a function that takes variable arguments each time. How to do for that???

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary In that case, [zip](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) terminates after the first sequence reached it’s end. You can use [``itertools.zip_longest``](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to pad with ``None`` (or any other value).

Comment: @JonasWielicki We don't pad with `None`(or any other value) in `roundrobin`, we need the item from next iterable in that case.

Comment: nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str_ascii_iterator' object has no attribute 'next'

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) (to unwrap the tuples) with [itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) (to transpose the elements in order to create an interleaving pattern) to create your result

```
>>> from itertools import izip, chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(izip(range(5), "hello")))
[0, 'h', 1, 'e', 2, 'l', 3, 'l', 4, 'o']
```

If the strings are of unequal length, use izip_longest with a pad value (preferably empty string)

Answer (score 2):

A mixture of the two itertools roundrobin recipes for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) looks like this:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    try:
        iter([]).__next__  # test attribute
        nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    except AttributeError:  # Python 2 behavior
        nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))

print(list(roundrobin(range(5), "hello")))
```

Answer (score 1):

list(roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF'))

**Output :** ['A', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'F', 'C']

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    sentinel = object()
    from itertools import chain
    try:
        from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest
    except:
        from itertools import zip_longest 
    return (x for x in chain(*zip_longest(fillvalue=sentinel, *iterables)) if x is not sentinel)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for Python 3, use this

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

The difference is that Python 3's iterator has `__next__()` instead of `next()`.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution (for python 3)

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, zip_longest

stuff = (repeat("A", 2), repeat("B", 3), repeat("C", 5))


# Round robin through iterables
[i for i in chain(*zip_longest(*stuff)) if i is not None]
```

Got back

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Warning: This discards None. You could replace with another stand-in, but it is not a general solution for all use cases.

Answer (score 0):

for python3, you can use [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.interleave),
like this

```py
import more_itertools as mit
list(mit.interleave(range(5), "hello"))
```

##### Output

```
[0, 'h', 1, 'e', 2, 'l', 3, 'l', 4, 'o']
```

or use [pytoolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.interleave)

```py
import toolz.itertoolz as ti
list(ti.interleave((range(5), "hello")))
```

##### Output

```py
[0, 'h', 1, 'e', 2, 'l', 3, 'l', 4, 'o']
```

Answer (score -2):

from itertools import cycle

A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7]]

B = [[8],[9,10,11],[12,13]]

for p in A:

```
max1 = len(p) if  max1 <len(p) else max1
```

for p in B:

```
max1 = len(p) if  max1 <len(p) else max1
```

i = len(A)

j = 0

C = []

list_num = cycle(k for k in range(i))

for x in list_num:

```
j += 1

if j == i*3:

    break


if A[x]:

    C.append(A[x].pop(0))

if B[x]:

    C.append(B[x].pop(0))
```

Output=====> [1, 8, 4, 9, 7, 12, 2, 5, 10, 13, 3, 6, 11]

Comment: Please explain why your answer should provide better information than the other answers already posted to this question. If you keep being convinced it does, please edit your answer and fix the code block formatting.