# How to Interweave 2 lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need to find out how to interweave 2 list.
For example:

```
list1 = ['Hi', ' how', 'you', '?']
list2 = [',', 'are', 'today']
```

Expected Output:

```
Hi, how are you today?
```

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: You can use `zip`

Comment: I really haven't tried anything, because I have no idea how to tackle the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883826/interleaving-2-lists-of-unequal-lengths

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion

Comment: You don't know how to tackle the problem? Well, how would you do this by hand? You'd take the first string from the first list, then the first string from the 2nd list, and so on. You just need to translate that process to python code. If you don't know how to do *that*, then you need to read a tutorial. *Completing* the program may be difficult, but *tackling* the problem is easy.

Comment: Oh thanks. Didn't realize this had already been asked.

Comment: You can easily find your answer on stack but it's ok.
Using "Zip" you will get the output which you want.

>>> res = [output for item in zip(list1,list2) for output in item]